# How can I get a parent object of a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have been passed a method as follows:

```
my_function(MyObject.method)
```

Can I access `MyObject` from inside `my_function`, such that I can call `MyObject.some_other_method()`?

Please distinguish whether it's possible to do this on a class level and an instance level.

Comment: On a class level: no, unless `method` is a class method.

Comment: Not every method has a class: some methods like lambda-expressions, nested functions, etc. have no class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't recommend doing this but after a little poking around, you can access the object a function is bound to:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, _id):
        self._id = _id
    def a(self):
        pass
    def b(self):
        print("b: {}".format(self._id))

c = C('test')


# you can access the object the function is bound to with __self__
c.a.__self__.b()

def my_function(fn):
    fn.__self__.b()


my_function(c.a)  #  "b: test"
```

Comment: That's actually very useful. Why wouldn't you recommend it? It's very nice shortcut that's saved me a lot of extra code

Comment: Probably because if you need it, you are probably trying to solve an x/y problem - and in any case, it is probably worth looking at your design to see if it can be improved.  But I don't know your specific problem, so it is possible that this is the best way for you.

Comment: Depends on the use case obviously, but any code that relies on being able to reach up and out into the unknown to execute unseen parent code is going to be brittle at best and dangerous at worst. Having said that, best not to be dogmatic when there's a legit (limited) scenario!

Comment: Based on the little you've told us about it, it seems like you should be able to pass down the other functions you need to `my_function` in the first place. Better to give a function exactly what it needs (and no more) to do its work.